# Node features matrix with networkx graph

Tags: python, matrix, networkx

I am trying to extract two types of arrays from a graph from the python `networkx` library.
One such matrix would be the edge attribute matrix, which would have a size of `NxNxM` where `N` is the number of nodes in the network and `M` is the number of features in the network.
This matrix can be easily pulled out by iterating on each of the attributes of M to pull out the matrix as follows and then putting the matrices together in numpy.

Input:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(0, 1, thickness=1, height = 4)
G.add_edge(0, 2, thickness=2, height = 5)
G.add_edge(1, 2, thickness=3, height = 6)

nx.set_node_attributes(G, {0:11, 1:12, 2:13}, "node_type")
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {0:21, 1:22, 2:23}, "node_type2")

m1 = nx.attr_matrix(G, edge_attr = "thickness")
m2 = nx.attr_matrix(G, edge_attr = "height")
m3 = nx.attr_matrix(G, node_attr = "node_type")
m4 = nx.attr_matrix(G, node_attr = "node_type2")
```

Output:

```
m1 = (matrix([[0., 1., 2.],
         [1., 0., 3.],
         [2., 3., 0.]]),
 [0, 1, 2])
m2 = (matrix([[0., 4., 5.],
         [4., 0., 6.],
         [5., 6., 0.]]),
 [0, 1, 2])
```

However, when it comes to outputting the second matrix, the function I use does not seem to perform similarly and I don't understand why. My intention is to pull out a node attribute matrix of size `NxM` where `N` and `M` mean the same as above. However, when I try to do this I get the following:

Output:

```
m3 = (matrix([[0., 1., 1.],
         [1., 0., 1.],
         [1., 1., 0.]]),
 [11, 12, 13])
m4 = (matrix([[0., 1., 1.],
         [1., 0., 1.],
         [1., 1., 0.]]),
 [21, 22, 23])
```

Instead of what I would expect to get:

```
m3 = (matrix([[11],
              [12],
              [13]]),
 [x, x, x])
m4 = (matrix([[21],
              [22],
              [23]]),
 [x, x, x])
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for the second matrix?

Comment: Every matrix creation is up there. I dont underestand what you are asking for. @AveragePythonEnjoyer

Comment: „However, when it comes to outputting the second matrix, the function I use does not seem to perform similarly and I don't understand why.“ - what function?

Comment: I am talking about the nx.attr_matrix method